# How to add children to previously-declared nodes using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

Here is a simple TikZ tree:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {root}
    child {node {left}}
    child {node {right}
      child {node {child}}
      child {node {child}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In this example, the children are appended to the *root* node in the same statement. How to attach children (`child`) to the *root* `node` in a later statement?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (root) {root}; % declare root

  % do something else

  ... % reference root node and attach children to it
    child {node {left}}
    child {node {right}
      child {node {child}}
      child {node {child}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to do this because the *root* `node` is created in a loop.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Maybe you could post exactly what you have in mind. First, you may want to name the first node in the tree (especially if you create more than one -- you specified that root node is created in a loop).

Comment: I attempted to clarify the question. Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: I added a proposal, based on what I understood. Hope this'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I understood, at least I think I did.
Here's a proposal:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  % Create first node which is the fake tree root node  
  \node (root) {root};

  % Do whatever you want

  % Call back your fake root node and place your real tree node on it
  % using \phantom to exactly copy the fake one
  
  \node at (root) {\phantom{root}}
        child   {   node {left}}
        child   {   node {right}
                    child {node {child 1}}
                    child {node {child 2}}
                };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Same image is produced, so I didn't add any.
All this, provided you do everything into the same `tikzpicture`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but you can always name nodes to later reference them, like so:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \node (root) {root}
    child {node {left}}
    child {node {right}
      child {node {child}}
      child {node (one) {child}}
    };
    
  \draw[red] (one) to [bend right=60] (root);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I realize my question was not crystal clear. I updated it.

Comment: Ok, this is indeed a bit different that what I understood. However, naming nodes should still be key here, I guess.